# emacs debugger: how can I step-out, step-over?

Tags: debugging, emacs, elisp

I don't know why I'm having so much trouble groking [the documentation for the elisp debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugger-Commands.html).

I see it has a commands to "step-into" (d).  But for the life of me, I cannot see a step-out or step-over.

Can anyone help?

If I have this in the *Backtrace* buffer:

```
Debugger entered--returning value: 5047
  line-beginning-position()
* c-parse-state()
* byte-code("...")
* c-guess-basic-syntax()
  c-show-syntactic-information(nil)
  call-interactively(c-show-syntactic-information)
```

...where do I put the cursor, and what key do I type, to step out of the parse-state() fn ?   by that I mean, run until that fn returns, and then stop in the debugger again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'c' and 'j' work kind of like a step-out and step-over. When a flagged frame (indicated by "*") is encountered (the docs say "exited" but this doesn't seem to be how the debugger behaves), the debugger will be re-entered. When the top frame is flagged, they work like step-over; when it isn't, they work like step-out.

In your example backtrace, typing either will step out of `line-beginning-position` into `c-parse-state`. The frame flag should clear, so typing either a second time should step out of `c-parse-state`.

Answer (score 5):

When debugging, I press <kbd>?</kbd> and I see:

```
o               edebug-step-out
f               edebug-forward-sexp
h               edebug-goto-here
```

I believe <kbd>o</kbd> (it is `step-out`) and <kbd>f</kbd> (like step over) are what you're looking for, though I also find <kbd>h</kbd> extremely useful.

Comment: I know you're gonna find this hard to believe, but I Was using debug, not edebug.  What a difference!  thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Cheeso, ha!  I didn't even know there was a `M-x debug` until your question.

Comment: You were better off, not knowing. debug is impossible to use.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. I, for one, prefer `debug` to `edebug`, but to each her own...

As to `debug`, I use `d`, `c`, `e`, and `q`.

If you do use `debug`, one thing to keep in mind, which can save time and effort, is that when you see a macro call (starts with`#`) you can just hit `c` to expand the macro -- there is normally no sense in digging into the macro expansion code (unless you wrote the macro and you are trying to debug it).

In particular, for `dolist`, there are two levels of macroexpansion to skip over using `c`: one for `dolist` and one for `block`.

HTH.